# Deployment strategy for Office 365 SharePoint 2013 stuff

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

A SharePoint 2013 office 365 development site has following items in it which needs to be migrated to the office 365 UAT environments.

```
  OOB CSWP (Search w/p)
  Newsfeed w/p.
  Blog w/p
  Lots of Java script files
```

N.B. All are server side web parts only.

Basically I have to take the stuff from OFFICE 365 Dev a/c to office 365 test a/c where test a/c is totally different than dev a/c.

Now, what should be correct strategy and planning to migrate these elements to the UAT environment? Is site template is sufficient to migrate this?

Comment: You want to move from office 365 to testing or from testing to Office 365?

Comment: Basically I have to take the stuff from OFFICE 365 Dev a/c to office 365 test a/c where test a/c is totally different than dev a/c.

Comment: What's w/p and a/c?

Comment: w/p - web part & a/c - account

Answer (score 0):

Their is no OOTB method available to move the sites in Office 365. You have to choose the Between Manually or 3rd Party tools.

Third Party Tool

- Free trial is available: http://www.metavistech.com
- Sharegate, http://en.share-gate.com/

Or you can manully move the Content from One site to Other.
For more information: [Information about manual migration of SharePoint Online content.](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2783484?wa=wsignin1.0)

check the official response from MSFT rep: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/246085.aspx

Comment: waqar sarwar, even after going through 2 links which you have sent, correct steps are not clear to me. Can you please write main 10 steps to deploy the same to another (test) environment?

Comment: 1st two links are for the 3rdparty Tools, are you asking about them?

Comment: I am asking about next 2 links i.e.

Comment: Information about manual migration of SharePoint Online content.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/246085.aspx

Comment: Looks like you have less content and more objects i.e Web parts etc. I am sure you have to manually copy/ re-create stuff on the destination site. May be try to Save as template? other than that 3rd party is only option( you can try their trail)

Comment: If all server side OOB web parts. I know 3rd party tools are better but can we deploy with site templates only? Practically which steps developers are taking? Are they rebuilding everything or site templates are also frequently used? What is industry standard.

Comment: How content search web parts to be taken to the UAT? I don't think web parts needs to changed to app format, since many OOB w/p are working fine is O365.